# Trigger To Update The New Column For Future Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, concatenation

Have 0 SQL background.

Table Name: CartonInformationDev

Column Name:
CartonNum|StoreNum|Department|FullCartonNumber

Need to ensure all new inserts and updates of the old column update the new column.

Need to add a trigger for all INSERT and UPDATE statements on this table.

Whenever a new row is inserted or updated on CartonInformationDev, need to create or update the FullCartonNumber column with the correct, concatenated (StoreNum & CartonNum) value.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most products have their own versions of triggers.)

Comment: Using SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. For anyone trying to CONCAT two columns into one column when new data is being inserted:

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FullCartonNum] 
   ON  [dbo].[CartonInformationDev] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE CartonInformationDev SET FullCartonNumber = CONCAT(StoreNum, CartonNum)

END
```

Comment: This should be a computed column, not a trigger.